# How I can center a title on echarts4r?

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

Hi and thanks for reading me
Anyone knows how I can center a title on a plot maded with echarts4r? Im trying the following code, but it doesnt work:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:5],
  y = runif(5, 1, 5),
  z = runif(5, 3, 10)
)

df |>
  arrange(y) |> 
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_bar(y) |>
  e_legend(FALSE) |> 
  e_title("Título ejemplo", align = "center") |> 
  e_flip_coords()
```

Hope anyone can help me, I don't find anything :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved by setting `left = "center"`. See [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#title.right).

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = LETTERS[1:5],
  y = runif(5, 1, 5),
  z = runif(5, 3, 10)
)

library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  arrange(y) |> 
  e_charts(x) |>
  e_bar(y) |>
  e_legend(FALSE) |> 
  e_title("Título ejemplo", left = "center") |> 
  e_flip_coords()
```

[image]